# Cannot Add Previously Inserted Object to Another Object (Entity Framework)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have the EF classes OAFile and Email. I am loading the emails from the server and storing in the repository. The user can then list the e-mails and "associate" them with the selected file.

The email object is previously inserted into the repository, and I want to get the count of the emails of the file.

```
file.Emails.Add(email)
```

adds the email to the file object, but it is not being saved.

```
file.Emails.Count
```

returns always 0.

The email.FileID field is saved correctly.

What am I missing? How can get the number of email by calling file.Emails.Count?

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateInput(false)]
    public ActionResult AssignEmail(int emailId, int assignedTo)
    {
        if (emailId > 0 && assignedTo > 0)
        {
            Email email = repository.Emails.FirstOrDefault(x => x.EmailID == emailId);
            OAFile file = repository.OAFiles.FirstOrDefault(x => x.FileID == assignedTo);
            if (email != null && file != null)
            {
                email.FileID = assignedTo;
                email.AssignedByID = HttpContext.User.Identity.GetUserId();
                file.Emails.Add(email);
                repository.Save();
                return Json(new { success = true }, JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet);
            }
            else
            {
                return Json(new { success = false }, JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return Json(new { success = false }, JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet);
        }
    }
```

The Email class:

```
public class Email
{
    public Email()
    {
        Attachments = new HashSet<EmailAttachment>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int EmailID { get; set; }

    public string EmailIdentifier { get; set; }

    public int MessageNumber { get; set; }

    public string From { get; set; }

    public string Subject { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateSent { get; set; }

    public string Body { get; set; }

    public int? FileID { get; set; }

    public string AssignedByID { get; set; }

    public string AssignedToID { get; set; }

    public string EmailType { get; set; }

    public ICollection<EmailAttachment> Attachments { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("FileID")]
    public virtual OAFile OAFile { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("AssignedByID")]
    public virtual AppUser AssignedBy { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("AssignedToID")]
    public virtual AppUser AssignedTo { get; set; }
}
```

and the OAFile class:

```
public class OAFile
{
    public OAFile()
    {
        Services = new HashSet<Service>();
        Documents = new HashSet<Document>();
        Notes = new HashSet<Note>();
        Forms = new HashSet<Form>();
        Emails = new HashSet<Email>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int FileID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int CompanyID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(14)]
    public string OurFileName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string CompanyFileName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string AppUserId_Creator { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd.MM.yyyy}")]
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }

    public int ClientID { get; set; }


    [ForeignKey("ClientID")]
    public virtual Client Client { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Service> Services { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Document> Documents { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Note> Notes { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Form> Forms { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Email> Emails { get; set; }

    public virtual Company Companies { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("AppUserId_Creator")]
    public virtual AppUser AppUsers_Creator { get; set; }
}
```

**EDIT:** I am calling the file.Emails.Count statement below to check whether the file has any emails associated with it.

```
 public bool IsFileEmpty(int fileId)
    {
        bool isFileEmpty = true;

        OAFile file = repository.FindOAFile(fileId);
        if (file.Services.Count > 0 || file.Documents.Count > 0
            || file.Forms.Count > 0 || file.Notes.Count > 0 || file.CCTable != null || file.AccountingTable != null
            || file.Emails.Count > 0
            )
        {              
            isFileEmpty = false;
        }
        return isFileEmpty;
    }
```

**EDIT 2:** I am calling the IsFileEmpty() method in another controller (HomeController.cs) while populating view model for search results. The results rows display the Delete link if the file is empty.

```
public ActionResult FilesSearch(FileSearchViewModel viewModel)
    {
        var files = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(viewModel.Keyword) ? repository.FindOAFiles(viewModel.Keyword) : repository.OAFiles;
        var sortedFile = files.Where(x => x.IsFileOpen).OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedOn).ToList();
        sortedFile.AddRange(files.Where(x => !x.IsFileOpen).OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedOn));

        var resultsList = new List<FileSearchResultsViewModel>();

        foreach (OAFile file in sortedFile)
        {
            var resultsViewModel = new FileSearchResultsViewModel();
            resultsViewModel.oAFile = file;
            resultsViewModel.isFileEmpty = IsFileEmpty(file.FileID);

            resultsList.Add(resultsViewModel);
        }
        return PartialView("_FilesSearch", resultsList);
    }
```

Comment: the function count() on a navigation property will trigger a db call. if you didn't save your changes to the database, this call will obviously not find any related entities and return 0.

Comment: I am calling repository.Save(); to save the data. I can see the FileID column is updated in the database.  email.FileID = assignedTo; is working, but file.Emails.Add(email); is not.

Comment: When (or where) do you call file.Emails.Count?

Comment: I added the code where I am calling the file.Emails.Count in the Edit section.

Comment: try adding `virtual` keyword to public ICollection<Email> Emails { get; set; } in OAFile  class

Comment: Yes! That was it. Thank you @boran

Comment: Yeah, and now the question is: where do you call `IsFileEmpty`? Anyway, that's a *terribly* inefficient way to obtain a couple of counts.

Comment: @GertArnold I added the code where I am calling the IsFileEmpty method. Please see the Edit 2 section. I would like to hear your suggestions...

Comment: Well, you had your answer.